# How to add recursive rows to a table, until they reach the end of the page in ConTeXt?

Tags: tables, context, recursion

I have a table in ConTeXt like this:

```
\starttext
    \chapter{This is a title}

    \bTABLE
    \bTABLEhead
        \bTR \bTD a \eTD \bTD b \eTD \bTD c \eTD \eTR
    \eTABLEhead

    \bTABLEbody
        \dorecurse{100}{%
            \bTR \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR
        }
    \eTABLEbody
    \eTABLE
\stoptext
```

How can I set the recursion to only repeat the cell only as much as what will fill the remainder of the page?

Comment: Query `\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax` to get the remaining space on the page.  Retypeset the table in a `\vbox` and keep adding rows until it exceeds the space left.  Then place the box on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible algorithm would be to typeset the table in a loop, adding rows until it exceeds the remaining height available on the page.  Be warned that this is pretty slow.

```
\startbuffer[table]
\bTABLE
\bTABLEhead
    \bTR \bTD a \eTD \bTD b \eTD \bTD c \eTD \eTR
\eTABLEhead

\bTABLEbody
    \dorecurse{\the\scratchcounter}{%
        \bTR \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR
    }
\eTABLEbody
\eTABLE
\stopbuffer

\showframe

\starttext
    \chapter{This is a title}

    \scratchcounter=1
    \scratchdimen=0pt
    \loop\ifdim\scratchdimen<\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-2\lineheight\relax % why 2\lineheight?
        \setbox\scratchbox=\vbox{\getbuffer[table]}
        \scratchdimen=\dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox\relax
        \advance\scratchcounter by 1
    \repeat
    \advance\scratchcounter by -1
    \vbox{\getbuffer[table]}
\stoptext
```

Comment: You need to add a check that `\pagegoal != \maxdimen` else you will have to wait a loooong time for this to compile when used at the beginning of a page.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same idea as Henri Menke's solution, but instead of adding the lines one by one, I first measure the height of the row, and then use the built-in command `\getrawnoflines` to get the number of lines that will fit in the remaining space.

```
\define\calculatelines
    {\setbox\scratchbox\hbox{\bTABLE
        \bTR \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR
      \eTABLE}%
     \openlineheight=\htdp\scratchbox
     \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen % we are at the beginning of the page
          \scratchdimen=\dimexpr\textheight - 2\openlineheight\relax
      \else
          \scratchdimen=\dimexpr\pagegoal - \pagetotal - 2\openlineheight \relax
      \fi
      \getrawnoflines\scratchdimen}

\define\fillTABLE
    {\blank
     \bgroup
     \calculatelines
     \bTABLE
     \bTABLEhead
         \bTR \bTD a \eTD \bTD b \eTD \bTD c \eTD \eTR
     \eTABLEhead

     \bTABLEbody
         \dorecurse{\the\noflines}
             {\bTR \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR}
     \eTABLEbody
     \eTABLE
     \egroup}


\setuppapersize[A5]
\showframe

\starttext

\fillTABLE

\page

\section{New section}

\fillTABLE

\page

\section{With some text}

\input knuth

\fillTABLE

\stoptext
```